# Group using data from one query into another

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like below. It is created using a query -

```
NPI   Other_Columns
123   Several_Other_Columns
456   Several_Other_Columns
```

How do I take every NPI from this table and get a count of the number of times they appeared in another table? The structure of the other table is like so -

```
Claim_id  NPI1  NPI2  NPI3  NPI4  NPI5  NPI6  NPI7  NPI8
```

If NPIs in the first table, show in any field in the second table, we want to count that claim.s

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what you want to do and what your problem is. Please edit your question to add detail

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first task is the join

```
SELECT
   t1.npi,
   t1.other_columns,
   t2.claim_id
FROM table1 as t1
JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.npi in (t2.np1,t2.np2,t2.np3,t2.np4,t2.np5,t2.np6,t2.np7,t2.np8)
```

that gets you all the things joined.

Now count those..

```
SELECT
   count(t2.claim_id)
FROM table1 as t1
JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.npi in (t2.np1,t2.np2,t2.np3,t2.np4,t2.np5,t2.np6,t2.np7,t2.np8)
```